# Lenovo y700 Task Manager Ram Confusion

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop, task-manager

I own a y700 gaming laptop and I know it only has 2 ram slots. But what has me confused is in task manager in the memory section under CPU I see "Slots used 2/4"

[image: "Image that explains it self"]

What does this actually mean 2/4?  What slots am I over looking?

Comment: Evidently Windows is interpreting the slots incorrectly, I use CPU-Z to see the real memory config....http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing memory slots.  The Lenovo Y700 ideapad uses the Intel HM170 Chipset.  **M** being mobile. It [supports](http://psref.lenovo.com/syspool%5CSys/PDF/Lenovo%20Laptops/ideapad%20Y700/ideapad_Y700_spec-win481.pdf):

> PC4-17000 2133MHz DDR4, two 260-pin SO-DIMM sockets.

A close cousin, the Y700 ideacenter Desktop uses Intel H170 Chipset.  This chip set [can support](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool%5CSys/PDF/Lenovo%20Desktops/ideacentre%20Y700/ideacentre_Y700_Platform_Specifications-win484.pdf):

> PC4-17000 2133MHz DDR4, four 288-pin UDIMM sockets

Maybe Windows 10 confusion is that these chipsets look similiar?  Hard to say, but rest assured, you only have two slots.